# error while deserializeing .dat file

Tags: java, database, excel, serialization, deserialization

My teacher provide  me the serilaized file.. I have not created it my self .. while deserilaizing the file i get following error

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: netflix.memreader.FeatureWriter; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 3279065858639389501, local class serialVersionUID = -7190666486441488760
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:562)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1583)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1732)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
    at netflix.memreader.FeatureWriter.deserialize(FeatureWriter.java:327)
    at netflix.memreader.MemReader.readFeaturesFromMem(MemReader.java:811)
    at netflix.memreader.MemReader.main(MemReader.java:727)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at netflix.memreader.MemReader.readFeaturesFromMem(MemReader.java:814)
    at netflix.memreader.MemReader.main(MemReader.java:727)
```

Comment: here is code public static FeatureWriter deserialize(String fileName)     {      try  {  FileInputStream fis    = new FileInputStream(fileName);
               ObjectInputStream in   = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
               
               return (FeatureWriter) in.readObject(); //deserilize into memReader class 
               
           }
           
           catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
               System.out.println("Can't find class");
               e.printStackTrace();   }
           catch(IOException e) { System.out.println("IO error"); e.printStackTrace();        }

Comment: Add your code to your post (using *edit*).

Comment: include code in the question itselft

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the exception says ,

> local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID, local
>   class serialVersionUID

The serialized object has the different `serialVersionUID` . when you are trying to de-serialize the object , the comipler will genrate the `serialVersionUID` if you dont specify the default one.

`serialVersionUID` may vary on same objects across different compilers (on various platforms). You may add the ,

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = -7190666486441488760;
```

Comment: Have you hard-coded the value in the serialised file ? Did you get the same error still